# Permission Denied error in IE6 Start of JavaScript tag in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer

for some reason, I get "Permission Denied" for line 20 in my .aspx when trying to view it from our dev server.  Line 20 is simply the start of the JavaScript tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // variables
  var firstProductID;
  var lastProductID;
  var getProductIDs = new Array();
```

...

Comment: Are you including javascript from someplace else?  i.e. "<script src=...>"

Comment: no, this is a test .aspx page, it's right in it.  And this page works fine in FireFox and the rest.

Comment: might help if you pasted the full rendered html source

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do an xhr (ajax) request to another domain?

Turn on [script debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx) in ie, reload the page and when you hit this error it will ask if you want to debug. You can debug in visual studio or ie debugger tools (if you have ie8) and youll see the exact script causing the issue.

The line numbering in the error is never what it seems due to included js libs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Line numbers can be very misleasing if you are trying to match up the line number IE gives you with the line number in the ASPX file (because ASP.NET can produce HTML that you won't see in the ASPX source view).

If you do a View Source in IE6 is line 20 still the start of your script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have a SCRIPT tag with a SRC attribute that is pointed to a file that does not exist.

Check your path.